# How to bind to a control within an ASP.NET ListView

Tags: asp.net, linq, data-binding

I have a list that I need to bind to a List I get from an API. The list looks like this:

```
struct DataItem { int level; string name; Guid key };
List<DataItem> myList = API.GetList();
ListView1.DataSource = myList;
ListView1.DataBind();
```

All this works fine for display. However, the table must edit the level value. I am unsure how to make that happen. I have tried event handlers on the listView, but they are never called. I have tried a text box for the level field (with both Bind and Eval) and an event handler OnTextChanged, but the event handler is never called. (I have tried with various combiniations of AutoPostBack and ViewState enabled.)

How can I programatically edit this data structure?

Answer (score 0):

Two way data binding you are trying to implement here won't work like this - List doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged (someone correct me if I'm wrong).

You may consider using a plain old DataTable which can be two-way-bound out-of-the-box. If performance is not a highly critical issue, converting your List to a DataTable (and back, depending on what you want to do with the modified data) is simple enough, rather than struggling with custom implementations of list types.